# MySQL Connection to data base to java

Tags: java, mysql

I cannot connect to my MySQL database, and so I can't INSERT any data. How can I solve the problem?

Here is my code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String query = "INSERT INTO tbl_login (id, tfname, password) VALUES (NULL,'" + tf.getText() + "', '" + pf1.getText() + "')";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prog", "root", null);
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        java.sql.PreparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connected to Database ");
        rs.executeUpdate();

        info1 tbl_login = new info1();
        tbl_login.main(null);
        frame.dispose();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot find Database Name ");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException et) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot find MySQL Driver ");
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: no error but can't connect it to the database and no show of data in to the table thankyou sir! btw i use XAMPP

Comment: You are not setting the password while connecting. That might be why it's not able to connect.

Comment: use password instead of null

Comment: sir darshan mehta can i add you to messenger/facebook to see the problem thankyou sir for helping me

Comment: Sir onkar can you show me the code please thankyou needed for finals haha im sorry im just a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Empty String` instead of `null` for password as:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prog","root","");
```

Comment: sir thankyou and i having error on this but still runnable //java.sql.PreparedStatement  = con.prepareStatement(query);
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connected to Database ");
       //rs.executeUpdate();

Comment: at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
if i submit data

Comment: That error does not look complete, I'd expect the top line to be in your class, and it also looks like the problem is with your UI, not the database connection.